# Is it possible to access the inner controls of a custom control in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have a custom control `PickerWithDropdownIcon` that is an `AbsoluteLayout` with a `Picker` and other controls inside. I am wondering if there is a way to access that inner `Picker` from XAML that uses the `PickerWithDropdownIcon` control.

PickerWithDropdownIcon.xaml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:svg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
                x:Class="CollateralUploader.XAMLHelpers.PickerWithDropdownIcon">

  <Picker x:Name="InnerPicker" />

  <svg:SvgCachedImage AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.5,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                Source="resource://CollateralUploader.Images.icon-down_arrow.svg">
    <svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PickerArrow_Tapped" />
    </svg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
  </svg:SvgCachedImage>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

In my `View` I'd like to do something like this:

```
<xh:PickerWithDropdownIcon>
  <InnerPicker.SelectedItem="{Binding VehicleNumberText}" />
  <InnerPicker.Items>
    <x:String>Vehicle 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Vehicle 2</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</xh:PickerWithDropdownIcon>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: In my knowledge, you cannot directly access it but to make changes to it you can use [Bindable Properties](https://xamarinhelp.com/bindable-properties-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: @G.hakim I'm familiar with bindable properties, but what do you suggest I should make into a bindable property?

Comment: Whatever change you wanna do in the child do it through a bindable property in the parent!?